# Function not running?!? Tuple error?

Tags: function, python-3.x, tuples, attributeerror

running python 3.0

I am receiving a "AttributeError :'tuple' object has no attribute replace" error code based on three function made to deal with higher numbers (above 1 million). Unfortunately the function does not seem to be executing as the tuple is resulting in a ().

Function code piece -

```
def under_ten_million(value):                                       #     under 10000000
    textnumber = str(test_n)
    firstdigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthdigit, fifthdigit, sixthdigit, seventhdigit = textnumber
    words.append(million_list[int(firstdigit)])
    if int(sixthdigit) >= 2:
        words.append(hundreds_list[int(secondDigit)])
        words.append(decades_list[int(thirdDigit)-1])
        words.append(thousand_list[int(fourthdigit)])
        words.append(hundreds_list[int(fifthdigit)])
        words.append(decades_list[int(sixthdigit)-1])
        words.append(number_list[int(seventhdigit)])
    elif int(sixthdigit) < 2:
        words.append(hundreds_list[int(secondDigit)])
        words.append(decades_list[int(thirdDigit)-1])
        words.append(thousand_list[int(fourthdigit)])
        words.append(hundreds_list[int(fifthdigit)])
        if int(sixthdigit + seventhdigit) == 10:
            words.append(teen_list[1])
            words.append(number_list[0])
        elif int(sixthdigit + seventhdigit) > 10:
            words.append(teen_list[int(seventhdigit)+1])
            words.append(number_list[0])
    return words
```

( the point of the entire code is to input numbers and output the word value for said number. I am doing this with incrimental functions that will be used based off the input number in a if statement. An Example of how the program runs - input = 345942, output = three hundred forty five thousand nine hundred forty two)

As you can see below based on the print code I still have 2 more identical codes below "under_ten_million" (with only 1 or 2 extra lines to acommodate the new numbers).

The part of code attempting to print the results -

```
# Tests where the number lies in terms of function use, then provides correct function.

string_of_words = ()

if n <= 10:
    under_ten(n)
    string_of_words = words[0]
elif 10 < n < 100:
    under_hundred(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1]
elif 100 < n < 1000:
    under_thousand(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2]
elif 1000 < n < 10000:
    under_ten_thousand(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3]
elif 10000 < n < 100000:
    under_hundred_thousand(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[4]
elif 100000 < n < 1000000:
    under_million(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[4] + " " + words[5]
elif 10000000 < n < 100000000:
    under_ten_million(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[5] + " " + words[6]
elif 100000000 < n < 1000000000:
    under_hundred_million(n)
    string_of_words = words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[4] + " " + words[5] + " " + words[6] + " " + words[7]
elif 1000000000 < n < 10000000000:
    under_billion(n)
    string_of_words = words [0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + " " + words[4] + " " + words[5] + " " + words[6] + " " + words[7] + " " + words[8]

print(string_of_words.replace(' zero', ''))
```

I have similar ( basically identical ) functions working perfectly fine which is why I am confused as to why the numbers exceeding 1 million do not compute.  If you'd like the whole code (nearly 250 lines) I can upload that as well!

Thank you!

Comment: At the start of the second block of code: `string_of_words = ()`. That is an empty tuple. The error message should then become evident.

Comment: But this worked for 6 other functions below 1,000,000. The tuple gets filled by the accessed list value and then put into the string? I don't understand why it doesn't work above 1,000,000

Comment: Have you tried debugging and print the value of `n` where things go wrong?